# two data in x-axis (categories and date)

Tags: java, netbeans

This is my bar chart code. The chart is successfully created based on all product profit, in particular month and year. I want to see the profit for every type of product in particular month. How can I accomplish this?

```
double summary = 0;
try {
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    String sql = "select date,sum(profit) from invoice_table WHERE date LIKE '" +
        year.getYear() + "-" + (month.getMonth() + 1) + "%'  group by date";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
          Date date = rs.getDate("date");
          summary = rs.getDouble("sum(profit)");

          dataset.setValue(summary, "Profit", date);
    }

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D(
        "Report", "Date", "Profit", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false
    );
    CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
    p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.blue);
    ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Report", chart);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 650);

} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```